# Smarty Template Engine - File get contents

Tags: php, json, smarty

i try to read external data with file_get_contents with smarty

However, i get this error.

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/serendipity/templates/templates3/index.tpl line 107]: [plugin] (secure mode) modifier 'file_get_contents' is not allowed (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1934) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/serendipity/bundled-libs/Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1093
```

Is there any other way to get data?Or how can i allow smarty to use this function?

Comment: Are you calling this IN smarty? You should assign it to smarty from your PHP file using $smarty->assign('var', $var); **edit** could you show some code of what you're trying to do, or where your using this?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly and why with in tpl file?

Comment: {assign var=data value='http://path.to/JSON'|file_get_contents}
            {$data|@print_r} i did this actually

Comment: Don't know much about JSON, but try to assign that value via your controller (PHP). Something like this: $smarty->assign('data', 'path.to/JSON'|file_get_contents); And then in .tpl say {$data}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [{fetch}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.fetch.tpl) plugin can be of help here. In any case, @shadyyx isn't wrong. You might just want to assign the contents and make your life simpler.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is config the smarty security settings.

The source code is as below:

```
if ($smarty->security && !in_array($_name, $smarty->security_settings['MODIFIER_FUNCS'])) {
    $_message = "(secure mode) modifier '$_name' is not allowed";
} else {
    if (!function_exists($_name)) {
        $_message = "modifier '$_name' is not implemented";
    } else {
        $_plugin_func = $_name;
        $_found = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that You are in secure mode. This means that Smarty does not allow You to run a PHP scripts (depends on the secure mode level) or call many PHP functions.

Either You can turn the safe mode OFF that I do not recommend or You should place the PHP code into Your controller and assign var within PHP controller:

```
...
$data = file_get_contents('path_to_json');
$smarty->assign('data', $data);
...
```

OR

```
$smarty->assign('data', file_get_contents('path_to_json'));
```